# How to prove (∀ x, p x ∨ r) ↔ (∀ x, p x) ∨ r in Lean?

Tags: lean

My prove is below but it's wrong,
 and i don't know how to corrrect this

```
      assume h : ∀ x, p x ∨ r, assume a: α,
      or.elim (h a)
      (assume hl: p a,
        show p a ∨ r, from
         or.inl hl)
      (assume hr: r,
        show p a ∨ r, from or.inr hr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lizhengxian Does this example help ([online Lean editor](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#code=variables%20%7B%CE%B1%20%3A%20Type*%7D%20%28p%20%3A%20%CE%B1%20%E2%86%92%20Prop%29%20%28r%20%3A%20Prop%29%20%5Bdecidable%20r%5D%0A%0Aexample%20%3A%20%28%E2%88%80%20x%2C%20p%20x%20%E2%88%A8%20r%29%20%E2%86%94%20%28%E2%88%80%20x%2C%20p%20x%29%20%E2%88%A8%20r%20%3A%3D%0Abegin%0A%20%20split%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20assume%20h%2C%0A%20%20%20%20by_cases%20hr%20%3A%20r%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20right%2C%20assumption%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20left%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20assume%20x%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20specialize%20h%20x%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20cases%20h%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20assumption%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20contradiction%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20assume%20h%20x%2C%0A%20%20%20%20cases%20h%20with%20h%20h%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20left%2C%20apply%20h%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20right%2C%20assumption%20%7D%20%7D%0Aend)):

```
variables {α : Type*} (p : α → Prop) (r : Prop) [decidable r]

example : (∀ x, p x ∨ r) ↔ (∀ x, p x) ∨ r :=
begin
  split,
  { assume h,
    by_cases hr : r,
    { right, assumption },
    { left,
      assume x,
      specialize h x,
      cases h,
      { assumption },
      { contradiction } } },
  { assume h x,
    cases h with h h,
    { left, apply h },
    { right, assumption } }
end
```

Comment: Thanks, It is really helpful